# Customize incremention of page number in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, numbering

I want two pages that face each other to have the same page number. In other words, have `Current Spread Number` instead of `Current Page Number`.

How can I increment/decrement page number for a page in InDesign? I wanted to see if there is a way to do some math on variables like `Current Page Number` such as adding a value to it.

It's a really basic thing that I think InDesign should be able to do, but I did not find any documentation for that, anywhere on the web!

Comment: Hey Fajad and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about the site